# Saving an Image Java Paint

Tags: java

I have built a java program that allows you to drawn on a canvas.
is there a way to save the canvas as an image? I don't know what I would have to do to save the canvas. any help will be appreciated. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.

It will allow you to create an Image of any component.

Comment: how do I save the canvas as an image though. oh did't see the ScreenImage class in your message